# C++ MFC applicaiton runs slow on windows 7 but snappy on XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a `C++ MFC` application (that was written pre 2000), I've compiled it in Visual studio 2012 and runs responsively in `Windows XP`, although it runs very slow in `Windows 7`. 
For example when trying to open a file using the open file dialog the application takes around 3 seconds to display the dialog and then around 7 seconds to open the file once the file has been selected.
To run it in `Windows 7` I do require the `C++` redistributable package.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: Give us some more details. Does everything in the application run more slowly or only opening the file. Maybe you should use a debugger to narrow down which parts of your software run slowly.

Comment: Have you tried running it in XP compatibility mode?

Comment: After more testing I did solve the problem. At the point of accessing files the application was slowing down. It wasn't windows 7 specific in the end it was PC specific after more and more tracing and not being able to put my finger on it. I noticed that the application was using HP dll's (in the module list in VS). It turns out that if you have a fingerprint reader or file encryption installed on your PC, the dll files will conflict with MFC application controls. 

Removing these tools fixed the application. (Digital Persona Pro)

Related Microsoft link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ MFC application controls will run slow in Windows 7 and windows vista if they are reading or writing to files when file encryption and fingerprint readers are installed on the PC. In my case the problem application was Digital Persona Pro. And the problem dll's were DpFbView.dll & DPClback.dll